Wrapper for OpenAI Whisper?
I want to execute OpenAI's Whisper from the command line and transcribe a directory with thousand of soundfiles. You can use the command line client for that but the command line client doesn't offer all the options the corresponding libraries offer. I am looking for some command line wrapper for these libraries. Does something like that exist?
